# AVAudioSession route change iOS 12

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudiosession, ios12

I am having following after upgrading to iOS 12 & XCode 10:

```
 2018-09-20 11:58:09.622656+0400 MyApp-Swift[1027:137400] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port Speaker (type: Speaker)
```

Any idea what it is, is it a bug in app or known issue in iOS 12?

Comment: I have the same issue, does it keep reoccurring in your console log, or does it just come up once? Every new version of Xcode always seems to add something to the logs lol

Comment: It keeps happening on every route change

Comment: Is an error being returned to your app or is it just a log message?

Comment: It's a log message

Comment: I have the issue too. Thought it was to do with needing to update a few Audio related commands from Swift 4 to Swift 4.2. But no. Did you figure it out?

Comment: It's a bug in iOS 12, though a harmless one.